# Prove that if $y= 2x+\sin(y-2x)$, then $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is equal to $2$ using implicit differentiation

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

If ${y= 2x+\sin(y-2x)}$, then $\frac{dy}{dx}$  is equal to $2$. I solved it and got stuck with ${y'}= \frac{2-2\cos(2x-y)}{1-\cos(2x-y)}$. I end up getting zero as my numerator. Do I still need to use an identity here?

Comment: Do you notice the cancellation?

Answer (score 1):

Note that $2-2\cos(2x-y)=2\left(1-\cos(2x-y)\right)$.

By the way, $\cos(y-2x)=\cos(2x-y)$, but the natural thing would be to use $\cos(y-2x)$, since we have $\sin(y-2x)$ in the question.

Comment: oh my bad forgot to factor! THANKS!

Comment: You are welcome. You had finished solving the problem!

Answer (score 1):

What is "qual"?  The only way $y = 2x + \sin(y-2x)$ can be true when $x$ and $y$ are real numbers is when $y-2x=0$.